# How to load API Endpoints from different folders in Express Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, endpoint

I currently use my load my API endpoints using this script:

```js
readdirSync('./routes/api').map((r) =>
  app.use(
    `/api/v1/${r.split('.')[0]}`,
    require(`./routes/api/${r.split('.')[0]}`)
  )
);
```

It pretty much reads everything inside the `routes/api` folder and the way in which I access the endpoins in POSTMAN is as follow:

```js
{{URL}}/api/v1/posts/123
{{URL}}/api/v1/videos/123
{{URL}}/api/v1/users/123
and so on
```

Now what I would like to do is to create endpoints that will be used as tools, let's say, a video converter endpoint?

Furthermore I would like to put this endpoint inside an `extras` folder within the routes folder, exactly like the image below:

[image]

The way to call the endpoins inside the `extras` folder would then look like this:

```js
{{URL}}/api/v1/extras/posts/123
{{URL}}/api/v1/extras/videos/123
{{URL}}/api/v1/extras/users/123
and so on
```

Then I decided to run my server with a second new script to see if it could run...

```js
readdirSync('./routes/api/extras').map((r) =>
  app.use(
    `/api/v1/extras/${r.split('.')[0]}`,
    require(`./routes/api/extras/${r.split('.')[0]}`)
  )
);
```

Well, it did not. I got an error thrown at me:

```js
[0] Error: Cannot find module './routes/api/extras'
[0] Require stack:
[0] - C:\xampp\htdocs\befree\server.js
[0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
[0]     at C:\xampp\htdocs\befree\server.js:165:5
[0]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\befree\server.js:162:29)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) {
[0]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[0]   requireStack: [ 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\befree\\server.js' ]
[0] }
[0] Error Cannot find module './routes/api/extras'
[0] Require stack:
[0] - C:\xampp\htdocs\befree\server.js
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Does any one knows if theres a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to create routes as I wanted

```js
/api/v1/extras/youtube
and so on
```

However, I was able to remove the error shown before by creating a function that iterates throught every single folder.

```js
// Define routes
const dir = './routes/api';

function getFiles(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).flatMap((item) => {
    // const file = item.split('.')[0];
    const routePath = `${dir}/${item}`;
    if (fs.statSync(routePath).isDirectory()) {
      return getFiles(routePath);
    }
    // return { singlefile: file, directories: routePath };
    return { item, routePath };
  });
}

const routes = getFiles(dir);

routes.map((result) => {
  app.use(
    `/api/v1/${result.item.split('.')[0]}`,
    require(`.${result.routePath.split('.')[1]}`)
  );
});
```

My youtube route is located in `routes>api>extras>youtube.js` but I still need to call it this way:

```js
/api/v1/youtube
```

Which I would like to say is good enough!.

**UPDATE ON 2021/10/27**:

I ended up modifying my loop and instead of using both returned values, `item` and `routePath`, I opted to use `routePath` only and modify the string which was more complete according to my needs.

```js
routes.map((result) => {
  const firstRoute = result.routePath
    .split(`./routes`)[1]
    .replace(`/api/`, `/api/v1/`)
    .split('.')[0];
  app.use(`${firstRoute}`, require(`.${result.routePath.split('.')[1]}`));
});
```

This small trick actually allows me to call my endpoins many levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` will read all the files in the provided directory, i.e. files *and* directories also. This means that when executing `readdirSync('./routes/api')` the directory name `extras` will also be passed to `require` inside your `.map` callback and since it's a directory the following will be done (from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)):

> [...]if the filename passed to require is actually a directory, it
> will first look for package.json in the directory and load the file
> referenced in the main property. Otherwise, it will look for an
> index.js.

In your case neither of above seems to be found, hence you get the error `Cannot find module './routes/api/extras'`

One possible solution is to filter out directories and only process files, e.g.:

```
readdirSync('./routes/api')
.filter(r => fs.lstatSync('./routes/api/'+ r).isFile())
.map((r) =>
  app.use(
    `/api/v1/${r.split('.')[0]}`,
    require(`./routes/api/${r.split('.')[0]}`)
  )
);
```

Comment: @Kirasiris: any feedback?